# Array index out of bond by putting Array Zero index value to another array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, loops, indexing

I am not understanding may be its some thing silly mistake in it

i have array

```
String[] Data
```

Below string is at zero index of Data,

```
[ ["Walls",  "Floors",  "Ceilings",  "Pillars", ,  "];
```

and i am willing to put it in loop in some new array at zero index like

```
String[] Description = null;

Description[0]=Data[0]
```

It gives error Array index out of bond??

what mistake is going on ?

i wanna put above string at index 0 of Description

hopes for your suggestion

**DETAIL:**

```
String[] Description=null;
String Manupulate ="";
for(int ques=0;ques<MultiQuestion.length;ques++)
        {
Manupulate = "["Walls",  "Floors",  "Ceilings",  "Pillars"],  "";
            String[] Detail = Manupulate.split("]");
Description[ques] = Detail[0];
}
```

Detail[0] will get `["Walls",  "Floors",  "Ceilings",  "Pillars"]`

I want to get Detail[0] value in Description[0].

I am using i will have to get Detail value in Descriotion[1] and so on till loop ends

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: If you don't want to be bothered by ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException while inserting I would recomend using a Collection rather than an array.

Comment: The code you added doesn't compile.  And if it did, it would give an NPE not an AIOOBE.  Please provide a SSCCE (see http://sscce.org) ... not fantasy code.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't initialize `Description`, it should give you `NullPointerException`, not `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try

```
String[] Description = new String[Data.length];
Description[0]=Data[0];
```

Comment: i need to initialize Describe outside fore loop to make it global so that Description would get information of some other records too

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined length for description.You need to allocate that array memory by :

```
Description = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Comment: i dont know its exact length if i use string[] Desciption; then it work ?

Comment: You can use length of the array `Data`.

Comment: i am using it in loop ok if i give it array length then it will add it at index 0 whole string at index 0 ?

Comment: Could you paste a code snippet as part of the question,it will make things easier.

Comment: @user3664724 - I think he means REAL code; i.e. code that actually compiles, and that actually produces the symptoms you are describing.  The code you added does neither.